# "fail to do" or "failure in doing", which is better in this case?

Tags: grammar, tenses, past-tense, gerund-vs-infinitive

> - I went to live in the small village to seek a simple life after my
>     failure in finding a decent job in the metropolis.
> - I went to live in the small village to seek a simple life after I fail to find a decent job in the metropolis.

Which sentence is better?  Or neither is better or worse semantically speaking, and the difference is a matter of personal choice?

Comment: The second sentence is impossible. It should be either "... after failing.." or "...after I failed..." or "...after I had failed...".

Answer (score 4):

The second formulation contains an error in the grammar. You need at least some version of past tense rather than *I fail to find*.

I suggest the following changes:

1) I would use the **past perfect** (i.e. *I had failed*) rather than simple past here to express this a further past relative to your main clause.

2) I would reorder the clauses such that the further past event occurs earlier in the sentence. (this is stylistic)

3) I would restructure the main clause to make the main verb the intentional seeking of a simple life. As you have it worded, it sounds more like an incident following from living a small village  than the reason you have chosen to live in a small village. If it is merely an incidental thing that you are now seeking the simple life, I would write the sentence differently.

Thus:

> After I had failed to find a decent job in the metropolis, I sought a simple life and went to live in a small village.

Answer (score 1):

Since you began the sentence using the past tense, you must end it using the past tense of the verb fail, which is "failed."
"I went to live in the small village to seek a simple life after I failed to find a decent job in the Metropolis."

The section "after my failure in finding" uses a passive voice, which is often discouraged.

Comment: *my failure in finding* is not a passive construction.